# Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments

Tags: angular, npm, yarnpkg

In my project I use the lib ng-particles v3.5.3 in my login and signin page, but it suddenly stopped working and returning in my terminal:

```
Error: node_modules/ng-particles/lib/ng-particles.component.d.ts:18:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

18     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgParticlesComponent, "ng-particles", never, { "options": "options"; "url": "url"; "id": "id"; "particlesInit": "particlesInit"; }, { "particlesLoaded": "particlesLoaded"; }, never, never, false, never>;
```

and also:

```
Error: node_modules/ng-particles/lib/ng-particles.component.d.ts:29:18 - error TS2707: Generic type 'ɵɵComponentDeclaration' requires between 7 and 8 type arguments.

29     static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<ParticlesComponent, "Particles", never, { "options": "options"; "url": "url"; "id": "id"; "particlesInit": "particlesInit"; }, { "particlesLoaded": "particlesLoaded"; }, never, never, false, never>;
```

I tried using yarn instead npm, changed the ng-particles to v3.6.0 but the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Had a similar error message for an angular component. The problem was a incompatible angular version.

My project was on Angualar 14 but the 3rd party component required >15. After downgrading the 3rd party component it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Go to this file in node-modules
[file - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwKFN.png)

And change this line
[line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNZuX.png)

insert this:

```
static ɵcmp: i0.ɵɵComponentDeclaration<NgParticlesComponent, "ng-particles", never, { "options": "options"; "url": "url"; "id": "id"; "particlesInit": "particlesInit"; }, { "particlesLoaded": "particlesLoaded"; }, never, never, false>;
```

Comment: that will work, but when you remove the node_modules and install again or in production mode the error will occur. its a workaround for workspace but not for long term view